# In laravel how to give user rating?

Tags: laravel-5.1

This is the user story-:
As an administrator I want to reward users for suggesting improvements to a submission so that I can increase their desire towards the system

I need to make user become senior according to their posts. 
as a example
first user level is junior member then  member and then senior member

Help me to figure out this!

Comment: This is way too broad as it is right now. What have you tried to do so far? Have you given any thought as to how you might implement this? Given that this all depends on your own project and how you have it set up it is impossible for us to give you an answer from what you've asked. You should give something a go and then come back to us when you run in to specific issues.
To get you started, you could set up a table that keeps track of the approved submissions they have made, you could then set up a scheduled job to read the table and update their role when they reach a certain amount.

Comment: yeah. i will check that